# Ultegra BR 6800's; Increase the reach to 53mm-54mm?

Tags: brakes

Can Ultegra BR 6800's pad-reach be increased to say, 53-54mm by filing the arm slot longer with a round file? Is there enough aluminum to do this without getting too close to the end of the end of the slot?

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  A photo would help, but I'd not recommend modifying brake components significantly.  Your other option is to look for off-set brake pads.

Comment: It might be possible (depends on how much of a risk you're willing to take), but there are plenty of 57 mm brakes from Shimano (R650) and Tektro (R359) that aren't that expensive. Personally, brakes are one of the places where I wouldn't risk it, esp. on an Ultegra level part.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this bruceDPac?  Are you trying to squeeze a bigger tyre in there?

Answer (score 1):

I increased the reach of my front 6800 by about 1 mm with a Dremel tool because the tops of the pads were extremely close to the tire mounted on my dynamo-hub rim when the front light was mounted. I don't recommend modifying the brakes in this way. No doubt it will void any warranty. I didn't have time to replace the brake with one with a longer reach before I left for a bike trip. I've ridden more than 2500k since the change and don't notice any difference in function. However, I believe my 1 mm modification was about 1/3 of what you're suggesting.